# How to get an auth code using ASWebAuthenticationSession?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, stripe-payments, aswebauthenticationsession

I'm trying to obtain an auth code from  [Stripe's OAuth endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference) using ASWebAuthenticationSession - this event happens after the my Stripe redirect url gets called.

Unfortunately, the authSession's completion handler doesn't call back with a callbackURL. And I need this callbackURL to query the auth code. I've read different articles on this topic but I can't figure out why my implementation doesn't work they way I expect it to.

Here's my code:

```swift
class CreateStripeConnectAccountController: UIViewController {

  var authSession: ASWebAuthenticationSession!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      configureAuthSession()
  }

  private func configureAuthSession() {

    let urlString = Constants.URLs.stripeConnectOAuth // Sample URL

    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    let callbackScheme = "myapp:auth"    

    authSession = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: url, callbackURLScheme: callbackScheme, completionHandler: { (callbackURL, error) in
       guard error == nil, let successURL = callbackURL else {
          print("Nothing")
          return
       }

       let oauthToken = NSURLComponents(string: (successURL.absoluteString))?.queryItems?.filter({$0.name == "code"}).first

       print(successURL.absoluteString)
    })

    authSession.presentationContextProvider = self
    authSession.start()
  }
}

extension CreateStripeConnectAccountController: ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding {
    func presentationAnchor(for session: ASWebAuthenticationSession) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        self.view.window ?? ASPresentationAnchor()
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider posting this question on their Github (if there's any), if no one answers this.

Comment: @Glenn good idea

Comment: @uchennaaguocha have you enabled your app for universal deep links? 
The alternative approach here is to completely handle OAuth in webviews, then have your "redirect_url" page manually link back to your iOS app

Also, what happens in your app when you've completed the OAuth flow in the AuthContext? It is expected to open the redirect url you've specified in your Connect settings

Comment: @hmunoz My original approach involved the webview. My user will create a Stripe Connect account, and once they're done, the redirect url will get called. It would redirect the user back to the app. Earlier this week my app got rejected because Apple deprecated UIWebview APIs. So, that's why I'm using ASWebAuthenticationSession instead of the webview.

Comment: @uchennaaguocha appreciate the details!

I'm doing the same on my end and it is working. i.e. Stripe Connect page -> redirect URL -> that page deep links to my iOS app.

Can you double check what is your url scheme and what url scheme your redirect page is redirecting to? 

You can also use WKWebView instead of UIWebView now

Comment: @hmunoz I just reviewed my code and I'm using WKWebView too lol. My url scheme is "bolar:app" and redirect uri is a Firestore cloud function url.

Comment: @hmunoz I think I know why my application got rejected in the first place. I was using a deprecated protocol called UIWebViewDelegate instead of WKUIDelegate. I'm going to give this a try and let you know it goes.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the issue is that you are giving `nil` for `callbackURLScheme`. You need to give a URL scheme that redirects to your app:

See apple's authentication example: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/authenticating_a_user_through_a_web_service

And here's apple's docs on how to create a custom URL scheme for your app: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm going to take a look into that now.

Comment: Yeah let me know. That seems like the most likely cause to me, but I could be wrong about that!

Comment: @wilco0 I tried it and it didn't work out for me. I create a URL type with my custom url scheme and called authSession.start(). By the time the authentication finished, authSession callback/completion handler didn't get triggered.

Comment: Do you mind posting your updated code so I can see?

Comment: I got update my original post. You should see a constant called "callbackScheme". It's the same url scheme that I used as a URL Type.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's old, but anyway.
Make sure, that `callbackScheme` and scheme that is used in `redirect_uri` are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your callbackScheme `myapp:auth` is incorrect format.

The symbol `:` cannot be used in the scheme name of a URI.

See the following `RFC` definition of `Scheme`.

> Scheme names consist of a sequence of characters beginning with a
> letter and followed by any combination of letters, digits, plus
> ("+"), period ("."), or hyphen ("-").

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.1

Thefore, revising the `callbackURLscheme` as `myapp-auth` or `myapp.auth` works well.

Answer (score 1):

try setting your `callbackScheme = "myapp"` to receive callback

and from your server-side it should return `"myapp://auth?token=1234"`

Hope it helps.